# Linux Crontab backup not working for a folder in root

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, crontab

I have a directory located at root...

```
cd /
li
drwxrwx---   8 root fred 4096 Nov  3 15:28 ourdirectory
```

Created a sudo crontab command...

```
20 8 * * 1-7 sudo tar -cpzf /mnt/backupdrives/backup.tar.gz /ourdirectory
```

But does not work, however if I change this rule to...

```
20 8 * * 1-7 sudo tar -cpzf /mnt/backupdrives/backup.tar.gz /ourdirectory/another
```

Joy all around :)

Thought it might have been rights or users issue, so have...

```
sudo chown -R root:fred /ourdirectory 
sudo chmod -R 770 /ourdirectory
```

But no :(

Any light greatly appreciated

EDIT - Just thought theirs not a file size limit for cron or tar is their ?

Comment: The command "does not work" how? What do you expect? What expected things don't happen? What unexpected things do happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have manage to get this workin....- however not 100% sure what I did.

It something to do with "Linux" v "Windows" world - the Crontrab commands where copied from windows notepad into Linux, by deleting all the spaces and re-typing them, it appears to have worked. But I may be wrong :(

Comment: It could be a line-ending issue too then.